# maximum function of a list is not working properly

Tags: python, list, numpy, max

I have a list of lists and I want to get the maximum item of it.

```
communities
Out[23]: 
     [[1, 25, 33, 37, 45, 89, 103, 105, 109],
      [19, 29, 30, 35, 55, 79, 94, 101],
      [2, 6, 13, 15, 32, 39, 47, 60, 64, 100, 106],
      [3, 5, 10, 40, 52, 72, 74, 81, 84, 98, 102, 107],
      [44, 48, 57, 66, 75, 86, 91, 92, 110, 112],
      [36, 42, 80, 82, 90],
      [12, 14, 18, 26, 31, 34, 38, 43, 54, 61, 71, 85, 99],
      [0, 4, 9, 16, 23, 41, 93, 104],
      [7, 8, 21, 22, 51, 68, 77, 78, 108, 111],
      [17, 20, 27, 56, 62, 65, 70, 76, 87, 95, 96, 113],
      [11, 24, 50, 59, 63, 69, 97],
      [28, 46, 49, 53, 58, 67, 73, 83, 88, 114]]

max(max(communities))
      Out[24]: 112
```

it should give me 114 but I don't understand why it gives me 112

Comment: `max` function on nested list will sort lexicographically. `max(map(max,communities))` will work!

Comment: but it doesn't make sense
at first max it  should give the max of all list inside, and second max should give the global max!!!!
so there's no othere bult-in function for that?

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) if you want to understand it better.

Comment: @ikkuh i think it's really weird...

Comment: It is counter intuitive but it is not weird. By breaking down the expression max(max(communities)) will first evaluate the inner max(communities), which is sorting a list of list, which turns out to be lexicographically (it's even more weird if somehow it sort by the maximum of the each list values).

Comment: @KevinWinata I understood, but in Matlab for example, when you say max(max(matrix)) it really gives you the biggest number in that matrix. so i thought it should work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it this way:

```
max(sum(communities,[]))
```

> output: 114

Comment: `sum` allows you to set an initial value from which to start adding. Being a list, it interprets that it should be adding lists together (that's why it works rather than trhowing an error), and then the maximum of the result is taken. Although this is not a recommended method for combining lists together @esysss

Comment: @yatu how? i put my list?

Comment: @yatu your `max(map(max,communities))` is better solution then using above solution

Comment: even better solution is `max(max(communities, key = max))`

Comment: Why is it better? Why would a max key be necessary using `max`? @Adelin I would say this is completely redundant

Comment: @yatu in OPs case? that's the requirement

Comment: There's no need for a key here, less for this key @adelin

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```
print (max([max(item) for item in communities]))
```

output:

```
114
```

Comment: even cleaner :)

Answer (score 3):

Because `max(communities)` is `[44, 48, 57, 66, 75, 86, 91, 92, 110, 112]`

You want to loop over communities and remember, via a variable, the maximum of each community:

```
communities_max = 0
for community in communities:
  community_max = max(community)
  if community_max > communities_max:
    communities_max = community_max
print(communities_max) # 114
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, Let me first answer why this happens and then tell you how to fix it.

When max function is applied on a list of lists. By default, it sorts iterables lexicographical ordering. for example when comparing lists it compares the first elements of both elements, if both are same then the next 2 elements and so forth, until the point where one of the elements of a list is greater than the other at which point that list is selected.

for example

```
a = max([3,3,10],[3,4,5])
print(a)
```

will select [3,4,5] because the second element 4 is greater than 3.

To solve this ideally, you can calculate it differently.

Since your list of lists are all sorted.

```
largest_value = max(communities,key = lambda x: x[-1])[-1]
```

Edit 1:
To help people understand how to do it for an unsorted array.
It is very straightforward

```
largest_value = max(communities, key = max)
```

Edit 2:
Sorry, I had misunderstood the max function algorithmic selection.
Thanks to @ikkuh for pointing it out.I've modified it to the correct version.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the proposed solution assumes the inner lists are sorted in ascending order

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the ordering of lists has nothing to do with the "mean of the list".

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but what if the lists were not sorted?

Comment: @ikkuh i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @ikkuh thank you for your correction, I was mistaken, I've modified the answer with the actual way the max function works. I've credited the edit to you as well.